# showing wrong path in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, path, controller

In Codeigniter,
My files are,

```
/application (folder)
 /controllers (folder)
   /welcome.php
   /upload (folder)
    /a.php
    /b.php
    /index.php
```

If I call `http://localhost/you/upload/a` it's showing correct controller(a).
and `http://localhost/you/` it's showing welcome.php (default controller).

But if i call `http://localhost/you/upload/` it showing same `welcome.php`(default controller). Not displaying `index.php`.

I wanna it's showing `index.php` or `404 error` or `url redirect to default controller`

Help me.

Comment: You directory structures seems stange to me.  I don't think you should have an upload folder but rather just a single upload.php

Answer (score 0):

In application/config/routes.php define the default controller

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'a';
```

Comment: why i change my default controller?

Comment: @KarSho bacause when you call http://localhost/you/upload/ without specifying index.php it redirect to default controller i.e. "welcome"

Comment: It's not redirect. URL stay ../you/upload only. But showing 'welcome' content.

Comment: @RajeevRanjan He is asking why `welcome` loads when call of upload is requested not to change the default_controller

Comment: @KarSho when we don't provide the controller it loads default controller.in my previous comment i should write it loads instead of redirect.

Answer (score 0):

In codeigniter controllers when you name your controller index.php it is not the same like
you define index.php in the main path because it is a controller and you have to type the name
of the controller.
also if you want to a controller to be called first
goto config than open routs.php and change the default controller

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'index';
```

than it will work

Comment: I mean index.php files are read first in the server. but it is controller.

Comment: index.php for 'access is forbidden'. Not a controller. i want 'welcome ' is default